# Error connecting with ssh - external network

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I know it's a very discussed topic, but after following lots of tutorials and checking most common troubleshooting problems, I'm facing the following situation

We have a small server in the office with Ubuntu 20 server installed.
ssh works fine in local network. Both with password and ssh key pair authentication.

The problem is. I can't make it work while trying to access from external network

List of steps followed:

- ssh generated key with with rsa
- copied public key to server
- router is configured to forward port 22 to local server ip
- permissions are configured to rw in .ssh/authorized_keys, both in client and server
- sshd config file apparently is correct, for what i've seen in the tutorials so far, but not sure though.

Commands and outputs:

```
ssh -i id_rsa  user@external_ip
Unable to negotiate with [external_ip] port 22: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa
```

After reading some topics I came across the following parameters:

```
ssh -i id_rsa user@external_ip -o HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa -o PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa
```

running this command, it still prompts for password. I input password and get:

```
Permission denied, please try again.
```

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: Please check the /var/log/auth.log for additional error information. Please also specify from what kind of client you are connecting.

Comment: Are you sure you forwarded port correctly and you are connecting to the server and not to the router or somewhere else? What kind of a router is it? Are you connecting to an external IP from the network that is being masqueraded into that IP (or, at least, being masqueraded by the same router where you set up the DNAT fort forwarding)? Try `ssh-keyscan external_ip` and compare the result with `ssh-keyscan private_server_ip`. That should be identical (up to ordering); is it?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov Unless there are some additional steps when it comes to ssh, I believe port forwarding is correct, because in the same router I also forwarded sql servers's 1433, and it's working fine externally. I'm trying to connect from a completely different network, router is a very basic model (askey rtf8115vw). I haven't been able to check keyscan yet, but I'll reply as soon as I can.

Comment: No specific. There is specific of accessing a forwarded port from within a network where it was forwarded to, however. You didn't answered that question.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov Sorry. Are you asking me if I'm trying to connect with public ip while being connected to the same router where I forwarded the port? If that is the question, then NO. I'm connected in a different router with a different ISP.

Comment: Try to enable a Hotspot on your phone, connect to that wifi network. Ssh doesn't use a lot of data. And can you do `sshd -T | sort` and post that